# How should I structure two maven projects so one uses the other?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have two projects that I intend to use maven (3.0.3) for and I would like to know how I can get the most out of maven for them. For reference, one is a *component* and the other is a *client* (such that the client can use the public classes of the component).

For the component, I assume that I build it using:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
    -DgroupId=com.checkersw.component \
    -DartifactId=checkersw-component
```

Do I now use the same command (calling it `checkersw-client` instead) for the client? Or do I generate the client as something other than an archetype?

Now, in terms of making the component a dependency of the client, how do I tell maven that the client is dependent on the component?

Also, will I need to manually compile the component before the "master" version is available in the client? Or can maven sort that out for me too?

Thanks in advance - I'm completely new to maven so any help is great.

Comment: You might like to read up on Maven (sub)modules.

Comment: Probably need to read up on more than just sub modules :) Check out dependency management and practice creating and building a few simple projects.